# Encoding format

Tags: c#, .net, api, model-view-controller

I want to Encode a file ,  i have already write some code for that but i think it's not working properly.
Code like this 
actually I am doing to convert a csv file and i am select encoding format on database through drop down list after selecting a encoding format like ISO-8859-1
or Windows-1252 and download the data file .after downloaded data file open in notepad and see that file it will not to be selected encoding format

```
case "ISO-8859-1":
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ASCIIEncoding.Convert(
                                        ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, 
                                        Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"), 
                                        convertToCSV(queryExecutionResult, fileName)));
    break;
case "Windows-1252":
    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ASCIIEncoding.Convert(
                                         ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, 
                                         Encoding.GetEncoding(1252), 
                                         convertToCSV(queryExecutionResult, fileName)));
    break;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working properly"?

Comment: PS that code probably *garbles* the text. `Encoding.ASCII` is the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that only contains English characters. `ISO-8859-1"` is the Latin 1 codepage most people mean when they talk about ASCII. Neither is going to help if the code that *reads* this file uses a different codepage

Comment: What are you trying to do? C# strings are Unicode, no ifs or buts. If `convertToCSV` returns a string, it's Unicode. `File.WriteAllText` will save it as UTF8, a **far** better choice than Latin1. A simple `var text=convertToCSV();File.WriteAllText(fileName,text);` would do. If you want to use a different encoding, pass it as a parameter to `WriteAllText`, eg `File.WriteAllText(text,Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))`

Comment: Yes It's not working